# how to check whether a string present in a file or not using java?

Tags: java, string, file

After reading a text file, how can I identify whether a string is present in that file or not using Java ?

I tried:

```java
public class SearchFaq {
    public static List<String> readFileInList(String fileName) {
        List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();

        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = readFileInList("/home/pavankalyan/Desktop/sample.aiml");

        Iterator<String> itr = l.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("About Company")) {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. How can I find if the string ("About Company") is present in the file or not?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: What do you mean by *not giving the correct result* - Please explain its current behavior

Comment: Youre seeing if the line EQUALS your string, not CONTAINS your string

Comment: The file contains the string that I have mentioned i.e. "About Company"), but it's not printing the value

Comment: Thanks, @zack6849, I tried using contains and its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(itr.next().equalsIgnoreCase("About Company"))
        System.out.println(itr.next());
```

You are calling `itr.next` twice in the above code. So, if a match is found, it will print the next line.

Change it as

```
String line = itr.next();
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("About Company")) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

However, you haven't clearly mentioned what *find if the string ("About Company") is present in the file or not?* means exactly. If that word must be a line in itself, then above code should work. If you want to print even if it is part of a line, then you must use `contains`

```
String line = itr.next();
if(line.toLowerCase().contains("About Company".toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: the issue is with equalsIgnoreCase() , we should use Contains("string")
then it will give the result